# Comparing in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
aDict = {'a': {'shape': 'square', 'size': 'large', 'color': 'red'}}
bDict = {'b': {'shape': 'circle', 'size': 'large', 'color': 'red'}}
```

I want to compute the value that is different in the two dictionaries (i.e. 'shape': 'circle' in this instance). How can I achieve this? I tried to convert the dicts into a set but doing

```
 set(aDict)
```

only gives me the keys, and I need to work with the values of the dicts. How can I do something like

```
set(aDict.values()) - set(bDict.values())
```

which returns 'shape': 'square'

Let me know if you need more clarification, thank you

Comment: What do you expect to be the result? `'shape'`? `'square'`? `'circle'`? `['square', 'circle']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aDict["a"].items() - bDict["b"].items()`?

Technically use `^` instead of `-` because you wish to know if there's a difference also from the other side. This gives you the result you were looking for though.

Comment: This seems to give me a "unhashable type" Dict

Comment: @shpakz Take the dicts out of the... dicts.

Comment: I believe so. Right now I'm getting a Keyword error 'b' but I think that's because my bDict is somehow null, which is an issue non-related.

I will choose answer once the time limit is up. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Following should do it.

```
for key,item in aDict['a'].items():                #go through aDict
   if aDict['a'][key] != bDict['b'][key]:          #if values are not same
      print(aDict['a'][key] , bDict['b'][key])     #print them
```